# How to use Beautiful Soup find all to scrape only a list that is a part of the body

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble scraping this wikipedia list with the neighborhoods of Los Angeles using beautiful soup. I am getting all the content of the body and not just the neighborhood list like I would like to. I saw a lot about how to scrape a table but I got stucked in how to apply the table logic in this case.
This is the code I have been using:

```
import BeautifulSoup

address = 'Los Angeles, United States'

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_districts_and_neighborhoods_of_Los_Angeles"

source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

neighborhoodList = []

-- append the data into the list

for row in soup.find_all("div", class_="mw-body")[0].findAll("li"):

   neighborhoodList.append(row.text.replace(', LA',''))

df_neighborhood = pd.DataFrame({"Neighborhood": neighborhoodList})
```

Comment: You're on the right track, I saw that there were some terms like `A-Z` which isn't probably what you need in the `df`, you could use this instead: ```for row in soup.find_all("div", class_="mw-body")[0].findAll("a", attrs={"title": re.compile(", Los Angeles")}):``` and then within the for loop, use `neighborhoodList.append(row.text)`. Remember to `import re` before you try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review the page source the neighborhood entries are within divs that have a class of "div-col" and the link contains an attribute of "title".

Also, the replace on the text during the append doesn't appear to be needed.

The following code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

address = 'Los Angeles, United States'
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_districts_and_neighborhoods_of_Los_Angeles"
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
neighborhoodList = []

# -- append the data into the list

links = []
for row in soup.find_all("div", class_="div-col"):
    for item in row.select("a"):
        if item.has_attr('title'):
            neighborhoodList.append(item.text)

df_neighborhood = pd.DataFrame({"Neighborhood": neighborhoodList})

print(f'First 10 Rows:')
print(df_neighborhood.head(n=10))
print(f'\nLast 10 Rows:')
print(df_neighborhood.tail(n=10))
```

Results:

```
First 10 Rows:
             Neighborhood
0        Angelino Heights
1                  Arleta
2       Arlington Heights
3           Arts District
4         Atwater Village
5           Baldwin Hills
6  Baldwin Hills/Crenshaw
7         Baldwin Village
8           Baldwin Vista
9        Beachwood Canyon

Last 10 Rows:
           Neighborhood
186    Westwood Village
187     Whitley Heights
188  Wholesale District
189          Wilmington
190     Wilshire Center
191       Wilshire Park
192      Windsor Square
193            Winnetka
194      Woodland Hills
195      Yucca Corridor
```